# Is there a way to isolate a state (or some states), such that the rest will not be executed in AWS Step Function (debugging)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

In my state machine, I have a long list of states. I would like to test whether each state or a subset of the states working properly. I have tested some of the beginning states, and they are working fine. I would like to test the rest without executing the beginning states.

Apparently, you can't make a comment on the Amazon States Language. In addition, One method that I tried is just skip them all by defining the "startAt" parameter to the state I am testing. Apparently, it will result in error, as the biginning state is not reachable. How do you go around this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a use case that we are aware of which we currently do not have a great solution for. We're working on solutions that should smooth out some of the difficulties with testing workflows. In the meantime you could break the state machine down into a number of non-overlapping subsets, and mock the inputs to each of these smaller state machines.